# Send public link by email

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

i am facing a little problem with email template in Alfresco Share. I want to send document's public link to users when somthing is uploaded.

The question is: how to include public link of a shared document in email template?
 what freemarker data tag references the public link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Share 4.2f under path

*share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\head\ **resources.get.html.ftl***

you have constant **Alfresco.constants.QUICKSHARE_URL** built like

```
Alfresco.constants.QUICKSHARE_URL = "${config.scoped["Social"]["quickshare"].getChildValue("url")?replace("{context}", url.context)?js_string}";
```

Didn't use it, but I'll bet you can do it first! ;)