# Get quickshare url with javascript

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to share a document with JavaScript and get its `share_id` programatically.
There is a `REST API` that can do that but I didn't know how to call it from script.

Any clues?

Comment: what exactly do you need? Get ID of what? Call webscript (REST API) from share - javascript controller, ftl? you had question that had similar goal -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619473/send-public-link-by-email Didn't it worked out?

Answer (score 1):

The following hack will do the trick. (edit: Must be executed from the classpath in the repository)

```
var ctx = Packages.org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
var qsService = ctx.getBean("QuickShareService");
var sId = document.properties['qshare:sharedId'];
if (!sId) {
    sId = qsService.shareContent(document.nodeRef).id;
}
```

PS: It looks even more ugly on 5.0.a due to rhino-1.7.

Comment: Hin thanx for the answer. I used your script but i get this error: "QuickShareService is not defined"

Comment: Now it tells me that Packages is not defined !!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674379/packages-not-defined/24676362#24676362