# Packages not defined

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

i wrote a script in javascript and used it in rules (share). The script start with:

```
var ctx = Packages.org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
```

I m getting an error telling me that "Reference error: Packages is not defined".

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The `Packages` object is only available for code which is considered "secure". This is most likely failing because the code is from a node in the Repository/Data-Dictionary. Put it  somewhere in the classpath (e.g. `classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/...`).

Comment: I am using this as a script to call It as an action. is it possible to declare script and put its code in such a classpath?

Comment: Yes. Declare a spring managed bean with parent "script". Set property scriptLocation using an instance of org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ClasspathScriptLocation.

Comment: I am totally new to this, can you afford an example?

Comment: I ve done like you said, but when I add a content rule to a folder, i can't find my script under Action->Execute Script !!

Comment: Assuming the system really picks up your action(!) bean definition, it should be available as an *Action* - not as a script you pick after choosing "Execute Script".

Comment: I can't find it nowhere in Execute action list.

Comment: Absolutely make sure your bean definition is picked up. If in doubt, place it in tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/foo-context.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use this object in javascript, you won't find that code anywhere in Share javascript files. According to [this](https://forums.alfresco.com/comment/135770#comment-135770) link, Package root scope object is only available for web script implementations placed into the Java classpath, due to security reasons.

Try writing Java code for your rule.

Comment: no way to overcome this and use it? here is why I want to use it: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653926/get-quickshare-url-with-javascript/24657718#24657718)

Comment: There is surely way for it, that's for sure, but it'll cost you time&effort. Wouldn't be doing it in your place.

Comment: Any clues clues to do this? My problem is i can not share a document from a script and get its public link.

Comment: No, I don't know how to make Packages root object available in javascript.